# No self reference to callback function possible

Tags: callback, swift, closures

don't know how to express the problem properly, therefore here is the code:

```
class Foo {
    func foo2(nextCall: ()->()) {
    }

    func foo(nextCall: ()->()) {
        func f1() {
            foo2(f1)
        }
    }
}
```

Condensed, but not sure if it the same type of problem:

```
class Foo {
    func foo(nextCall: ()->()) {
        func f1() {
            foo(f1)
        }
    }
}
```

The error message is: Cannot reference a local function with captures from another local function.

Any idea how to solve this problem? The provided function is used as callback function and somehow I'm wondering why the function cannot be used.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that does not compile? Your first code snippet runs fine here ([link](http://www.runswiftlang.com/s/qVsPYvb8)).

Comment: Strange, in Xcode it does not work. The call foo(f1) is marked with the error message. Got it straight from Xcode.

Comment: OK, did an update. Wrapped my code in a class as it was in my original file.

Comment: It seems you're referencing `f1` before it is being defined.

Comment: Forward referencing shouldn't be a problem. It is the salt of recursive programming.

Comment: The problem in your question is different from simple recursion. Swift will gladly accept 'func f1() { f1() }'. Eonil is right. There are other issues with your design too.

Comment: For calling a function only its starting address is necessary but to makes things simple just remove from the example code the class definition and everything is fine as the first and second comment indicates. It a problem caused by the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code successfully compiles:

```
class Foo {
    func foo(nextCall: ()->()) {
        var f1:(()->())!
        f1 =  {
            self.foo(f1)
        }
    }
}

Foo().foo({})
```

Of course this code does nothing. But if you implement as you want, it will work as expected.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's doing the trick.
Seeing this solution I think I've seen this before as a workaround. Anyway the problem is a nasty bug.